# How to remove Escape character in a string

Tags: c#, .net

I created an API that accepts one string parameter, but when i tried `""` as a `searchterm`, the output result has an escape character. How can I remove this? Thank you

```
searchterm = searchterm.Replace(@"\", String.Empty);
```

I tried this but still having escape character.

This is my code c#

```
public static JToken getRelatedKeywordsApiSpTable(string searchterm)
{
  JObject results = new JObject();
  searchterm = searchterm.Replace(@"\", String.Empty);
  DataSet ds = SearchData.getRelatedKeyword(searchterm);
  DynamicCollabObject relatedkeywords = new DynamicCollabObject(ds);
  results.Add("RelatedKeywords", relatedkeywords.dobject);
  return results;
}


public static DataSet getRelatedKeyword(string searchterm)
{
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@st", searchterm));
    return SQLDAL.runSPWithParams(SearchSPs.getRelatedKeywordApi, parameters, SearchSettings.badlands);
}
```

This is my endpoint

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("relatedkeyword/{searchterm}")]
public IHttpActionResult RelatedKeywordApiTable(string searchterm)
{
    return Ok(SearchBusiness.getRelatedKeywordsApiSpTable(searchterm));
}
```

My SP

```
select top 20 relatedkeyword as Keyword, [count] as [Count] 
from Transform_DIM_RelatedKeyword_Count  WITH (NOLOCK)
where searchterm=@st 
order by count desc
```

Output:

```
{
  "RelatedKeywords": [
    {
      "Keyword": "\"\"",
      "Count": 7
    }
    ]
}
```

[image: How i view the request]

My expectation should look like actual input searchterm

Comment: Hmmm, `Regex.Unescape()` or pattern like `[^\w\d]`... However question remains why does the API consumer sends bullshit

Comment: how is that? im not that good with c# i spend a day googling it. multiple of trials but still not working.. can you help me how.

Comment: @LaarniCortez, What the value inside `searchterm` and how it look?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: It might *appear* to you that you send `""` (empty string) but actually there could be some hidden characters in input. Check the length of your string before sending by copy-pasting it [here](http://string-functions.com/length.aspx). Since you presumably have empty string copy it with "" and make sure it's precisely 2 characters long

Comment: [object Object] this is the output of my api req this should not contain escape character

Comment: {
      "Keyword": "\"\"",
      "Count": 7
    }

Comment: the value of the searchterm is double quote or ""

Comment: @LaarniCortez Why do you add "" inside the string param, can't it be empty or null instead ? For example `{ "Keyword": null, "Count": 7 }` and then `string searchterm = ""` in parameters to make sure we have empty string there if null

Comment: this is what i tried toput in postman
http://localhost:50428/relatedkeyword/""
im doing component testing for this so i can tag my task for ready for testing however i find issue like this.

Comment: upon checking on sql, it returns the same searchterm as inputed

Comment: thats after relatedkeword then slash the input searchterm

Comment: @LaarniCortez I'm sorry but your question is unclear. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without it it's difficult for us to help you. Without knowing what exactly `SearchData.getRelatedKeyword` function does and bunch of other stuff it's difficult to tell what's the problem here. Edit your question or create a new one and add all related information.

Comment: im sorry for that, i already edited my question and add some codes

Comment: How are you viewing the output? If it's in Visual Studio, note that it will often add escape characters when it *displays* the string. The escape characters don't exist in the string itself, but they're added *for display purposes* by Visual Studio. You said `{ "Keyword": "\"\"", "Count": 7 }`, which implies that this might be the case?

Comment: i view that one in postman, for creating request so it will return a json file or the output i need.

Comment: Right, in your screenshot, the URL field at the top is `http://localhost/50425/relatedKeyword/""` -- it ends in two quote characters. The Keyword field in the response is also two characters `""`. It is then encoded as a JSON string - this means that it has to be quoted, and those quotes have to be escaped, so it becomes `"\"\""`. If you deserialize this field, it will become `""` again. The "problem" is not on the input side of things - it's that the output is being encoded as JSON.

Comment: I have to correct the output, my goal here is to create an api that doesnt have ui yet.  the only way i can check if its working by creating request in postman. My problem is how can remove the escape character there.

Comment: @LaarniCortez: *Why* do you want to remove the escape characters? The response is correctly formatted JSON, including a string *with (for JSON!) correctly escaped double-quote characters*. If you want to use that string on its own, deserialize the JSON and whichever JSON parsing library you are using will return the string *without* the escape characters. If you want to use the JSON as a whole, *do not remove the escape characters* as that would render the JSON invalid and might make it impossible to deserialize it again.

Comment: @LaarniCortez *Please* read up on how JSON works. You're getting very hung up on something which is very normal and very expected.

Comment: are you saying that if the escape character wanted to be removed it should be manipulate in UI?

Comment: @LaarniCortez: No. We are saying that once you read the value programmatically, there will be no escape character. The only reason why you are seeing an escape character is because you are looking at a JSON string rather than just the value itself.

Comment: Alright,I understand now i thought this one is an issue thats why iim trying to fix this to avoid bugs for my story. Anyway thank you so much for this. It really helps,  especially i learned how to debug using different approaches for removing escape character. This issue can be close now. Thank you so much